# Using :before and :after pseudo-elements with images

Tags: html, css, image, pseudo-element

I'm wondering how you format the Content CSS in a `::after` pseudo-element?

I'm trying to have an `h1` heading that has small images to the left and right of it.

My code so far:

HTML:

```
<h1>This Week's Photo Features</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

h1:before {
  content: ("images/NikonD100_40x30.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 11):

the [content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content) property can accept a url using this format:

```
content: url("the url")
```

**Demo:**

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

h1:before {
  content: url("https://picsum.photos/40/40");
}

h1:after {
  content: url("https://picsum.photos/40/40");
}
```

```html
<h1>This Week's Photo Features</h1>
```

Another option is to set the images as background of the pseudo elements:

**Demo:**

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

h1:before, h1:after {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  content: '';
}

h1:before {
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/40/40");
}

h1:after {
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/40/40");
}
```

```html
<h1>This Week's Photo Features</h1>
```

And if you use the images as backgrounds, you can ditch the pseudo elements by using multiple backgrounds on the `H1` element.

**Demo:**

```css
h1 {
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/40/40") left no-repeat,
              url("https://picsum.photos/40/40") right no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<h1>This Week's Photo Features</h1>
```

Comment: Simple and great answer!